# Nodejs: ENOENT on Twitter Image Bot

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner level programmer. I used some online guides as well as my starter knowledge. I'm attempting to create a bot that posts to twitter every hour. I keep getting the error ENOENT, which as I understand, means that it can't find the directory. Here is the error I'm getting (All I censored was personal information, but it's not censored in the actual code or error)

```
opening an image...
15.jpg
internal/fs/utils.js:269
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\####\Desktop\####\bot\images15.jpg'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at C:\Users\####\Desktop\####\bot\server.js:32:29
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\#####\\Desktop\\####\\bot\\images15.jpg'
}
```

It looks like its changing the name of the file to have images in front. I can't figure out why it's doing this though. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js')),
    images = require(path.join(__dirname, 'images.js'));

const T = new Twit(config);

function randomFromArray(images) {
    return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
}

function tweetRandomImage() {
    fs.readdir(__dirname + '/images', function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error:', err);
        }
        else {
            let images = [];
            files.forEach(function (f) {
                images.push(f);
            });

            console.log('opening an image...');

            const image = randomFromArray(images);
            console.log(image);

            const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images' + image);
            const imageSource = image.source

            b64content = fs.readFileSync(imagePath, { encoding: 'base64' });

            console.log('uploading an image...');

            T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error:', err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('image uploaded, now tweeting it...');

                    T.post('statuses/update', {
                        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
                    },
                        function (err, data, response) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('error:', err);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log('posted an image!');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    tweetRandomImage();
}, 10000);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: enodent simply means file non-existent.. so.. u might want to check up on that random function to ensure it doesnt point to an image that doesnt exist

Comment: but i do know your error exists in ```const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images' + image);
            const imageSource = image.source

            b64content = fs.readFileSync(imagePath, { encoding: 'base64' });```

Comment: ah i understand it now, the error happens on the line beginning with `b64content` but it is caused from the value created from `const imagePath`

Comment: try this fix, in the line of `b64content`, replace `imagePath` to `\`${__dirname}/images${image}\``

Comment: ooooooooh the ENTIRE error is clear now, sorry about the comments before, but the solution is simple.. change the line with `const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images' + image);` to `const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + image);` because i can assume now(idk y i didn't realise this before) that the 'images' part on your hard drive is a folder and you forgot the slash that says folder, then file name

Comment: @TheBombSquad That worked, thank you!

Comment: yea i just posted it as an answer, remember this as u keep coding.. im proud more newbies r joining the code world.. im excited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lesson of the day, ALWAYS WATCH THE SynTAx

```
const fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
Twit = require('twit'),
config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js')),
images = require(path.join(__dirname, 'images.js'));

const T = new Twit(config);

function randomFromArray(images) {
    return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
}

function tweetRandomImage() {
  fs.readdir(__dirname + '/images', function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
          console.log('error:', err);
      }
      else {
          let images = [];
          files.forEach(function (f) {
              images.push(f);
          });

          console.log('opening an image...');

          const image = randomFromArray(images);
          console.log(image);

          //THE ONLY CHANGE I MADE BELOW
          const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + image);
          //THE ONLY CHANGE I MADE ABOVE
          //THE ONLY PROBLEM WAS THAT YOU TRIED GETTING A FILE BUT HAVING A FOLDER AND A FILE NAME AS 1 THING UNSEPARATED BY "/" OR "\\" AND THE COMPUTER(& me who read it at first) THOUGHT TO LOOK FOR A FILE CALLED "images15.jpg" instead of "images/15.jpg"

          const imageSource = image.source

          b64content = fs.readFileSync(imagePath, { encoding: 'base64' });

          console.log('uploading an image...');

          T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log('error:', err);
              }
              else {
                  console.log('image uploaded, now tweeting it...');

                  T.post('statuses/update', {
                      media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
                  },
                      function (err, data, response) {
                          if (err) {
                              console.log('error:', err);
                          }
                          else {
                              console.log('posted an image!');
                          }
                      }
                  );
              }
          });
      }
  });
}

setInterval(function () {
    tweetRandomImage();
}, 10000);
```